# Desabilitar Salvar senha no Chrome em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

Teria alguma maneira de desabilitar a opção de salvar senha no Google Chrome, por JavaScript ou jQuery?

Me refiro à senha de login. Quando meu cliente se loga aparece para ele a opção de salvar senha, e apos ele habilitar isso sempre quando ele acessa o sistema ele continua logado. Eu quero desabilitar isso em qualquer Browser.

Comment: Gustavo, qual senha? refere-se a password quando faz login num site? Só no Chrome ou também outros browsers?

Comment: A senha de login. Quando meu cliente se loga aparece para ele a opção de salvar senha, e apos ele habilitar isso sempre quando ele acessa o sistema ele continua logado. Eu quero desabilitar isso em qualquer Browser.

Comment: Dei uma resposta com um método complementar, veja se ajuda como proteção extra.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lendo a resposta do [Markus Olsson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32386/2256325) no SOen, a sugestão é usar o `autocomplete` do HTML para dizer ao browser para não gravar informação:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="login.cgi" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Pode ler mais documentação sobre isso **[no MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion)** <sup>Inglês</sup>. Nesse link pode-se ler (traduzido livremente):

> A maneira mais fácil e simples para desabilitar perguntas para gravar Formulários  e Senhas e prevenir dados serem gravados é na cache da historia do browser é usando o atributo *autocomplete* com o valor "off".

**[Pelos vistos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** o IE11 decidiu quebrar essa regra e ignorar este comportamento.

Existem mais duas hipoteses:

- Fazer o `name` do input ser aleatório. Gerado do lado do servidor e gravado na SESSION por exemplo.
- Fazer o login via Ajax e aí em vez de enviar um form submit, faria o envio da password e limpava o campo sem o browser perceber.

Comment: Eu ja utilizo essa opção e mesmo assim aparece para meu cliente a opção de salvar senha após se logar. Eu gostaria de desabilitar isso pelo javascript.

Comment: @Gustavo eu entendi você não quer que aparece a mensagem do navegador para salvar os dados de autenticação. acredito que nesse caso a unica solução seja um login feito via Ajax.

Comment: @TuyoshiVinicius, acredito que vou ter que fazer isso mesmo. Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Gustavo, juntei mais duas ideias

Comment: `Eu já utilizo essa opção`, @Gustavo, por isso **é essencial** que você forneça todos os detalhes relevantes na sua pergunta.

Answer (score 7):

> Esta é uma resposta complementar e server-side. Estou postando como opção adicional.
>
> Vantagem do método: ele respeita o autocomplete do nome de usuário, e só protege a senha.

Usando alguma linguagem server side, você pode mudar o `name` do campo senha para uma string pseudo-aleatória, e usar um campo hidden para armazenar essa string, ficando assim:

```
<input type="text" name="usuario">
<input type="password" name="SYG2d7s6f1Sr874yYGJ4">
<input type="hidden" name="auxiliar" value="SYG2d7s6f1Sr874yYGJ4">
```

Assim, o campo senha (praticamente) nunca vai ser o mesmo, tirando a eficácia do que foi salvo anteriormente sob outro nome.

Aí, numa linguagem como PHP, basta usar assim:

```
$auxiliar=$_POST['auxiliar']

$usuario=$_POST['usuario']
$senha=$_POST[$auxiliar]
```

Um outro truque complementar é criar dois campos do tipo `password`, alguns browsers entendem isso como provável `form` de redefinição de senha, e não salvam neste caso (pode esconder um deles com CSS, por exemplo).

Comment: Cara, fantástico! É uma pena que ainda precisamos fazer malabarismos para driblar opções que alguns navegadores oferecem, sem ter como desabilitá-las...

Comment: **Só um adendo**:  Fiquei quase 2 horas para descobrir que eu tinha dois formulários iguais numa página. Um estava configurado para não completar, e o outro, não. Como estava usando AngularJS e `ng-model`, os campos do formulário sem a configuração preenchiam o formulário configurado, já que os `ng-model` eram os mesmos

Answer (score 2):

coloque o atributo autocomplete="off" acredito que não seja todos os navegadores que suportam.

> Documentação [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486(VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Nada do informado acima deu certo, mas criei uma solução simples.

Defina os três inputs do formulário, sendo dois do tipo "text" e insira uma função javascript no campo senha que no meu caso defini como "trocar()" e um campo "hidden":

```
input name="usuario_login" **type="text"** id="usuario_login" required
autofocus/>

input name="senha" required **type="text"** id="senha" **onkeyup="trocar()"**/>

input type="hidden" name="senha_login" id="senha_login" value="" />
```

Abaixo a função javascript que substituirá o caracter digitado no campo senha por "*" e transferirá o digitado para o campo hidden.

```
function trocar(){

  var tecla = event.keyCode;

  if(tecla == 8){

    document.getElementById('senha_login').value = document.getElementById('senha_login').value.substring(0 ,  document.getElementById('senha').value.length);

  }else{

    if(tecla != 9 & tecla != 13){

       document.getElementById('senha_login').value = document.getElementById('senha_login').value + document.getElementById('senha').value.charAt(document.getElementById('senha').value.length - 1);

       document.getElementById('senha').value = document.getElementById('senha').value.replace(document.getElementById('senha').value.charAt(document.getElementById('senha').value.length - 1), '*'); 

    } 
  }
}
```

Depois somente pegar os valores em linguagem de servidor "ASP", "PHP" ou outra e validar.

Answer (score 0):

passei pelo mesmo problema, hoje 10/09/2019 única solução que encontrei foi essa

colocar 2 inputs falsos antes do seu input

```
<input class="hidden" type="text" style="display: none!important; visibility: hidden!important;" ></input>
<input class="hidden" type="password" style="display: none!important; visibility: hidden!important;" ></input>
```

Answer (score -1):

Basicamente, o chrome reconhece qualquer form com apenas dois inputs (sendo um text e outro password) como campo de senha e grava qualquer dado que o usuário escreva lá. Depois dá sugestão de poder guardar os dados.

Recomendo que use dois inputs do tipo password sempre que for pedir confirmação de senha. Isso faz o navegador ficar confuso.

```
<input type='password' name='senha' />
<input type='password' name='none' hidden />
```

Answer (score -2):

Funcionou assim pra mim:
Remover o as bordas dos campos de imput e colocar a fonte com 0px ajuda a mascarar o mesmo sem muita dificuldade na sua pagina...
Outro detalhe não falado aqui em nenhuma resposta é que o ideal é que vc coloque esses 2 campos no inicio do seu form antes dos campos realmente validos, assim caso o usuario utilize a tecla "TAB" pra navegar entre os campos que precisa preencher o navegador nao vai "mover" a barra de digitação pra uma area que nao deveria ser preenchida obrigando o cliente a pressionar 2X o tab sem saber o pq aquilo ocorre.

```
<div style="widht:0px; height:0px;">
 <input type="password" style="widht:0px; height:0px; border:none; font-size:0px">
</div>
                   
<div style="widht:0px; height:0px;">
 <input type="email" style="widht:0px; height:0px; border:none; font-size:0px">
</div>

<-- SEU FORM REAL AQUI -->
```