# Como desabilitar a sugestão de senhas salvas no browser via HTML

Tags: html, navegador-de-internet

Tenho aqui a seguinte situação:

Criei um formulário em HTML para alterar a senha do usuário caso ele se esqueça dela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que ao tentar digitar a senha o browser expõe as opções de senhas já salvas, no entanto como essa não se trata de uma tela de login não é interessante que isso seja exibido para o usuário.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código HTML que estou usando é o seguinte:

```
<form id="form" action="@Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Login")" method="post">
        <div id="enter-options-box">
            <p class="title-bold">@ViewBag.UserId - @ViewBag.Identifier</p>
        </div>

        <label class="form-input">
            <i class="material-icons"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span></i>
            <input class="password-mask"
                   type="password"
                   autocomplete="off"
                   id="NewPassword"
                   maxlength="16"
                   name="NewPassword"
                   required
                   onchange="VerifyInput('NewPassword', 'newPassword-text'); this.setCustomValidity('');"
                   oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, preencha este campo.')"
                   onkeyup="CalculeStrength('NewPassword', 'strengt-bar', 'strengt-label')"
                   title=" " />
            <span id="newPassword-text" class="label">Nova senha</span>
            <span class="underline"></span>
        </label>

        <div class="box-bar">
            <div class="progress slin-bar">
                <div id="strengt-bar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
            <span id="strengt-label">Força da senha.</span>
        </div>

        <label class="form-input">
            <i class="material-icons"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></i>
            <input class="password-mask"
                   type="password"
                   autocomplete="off"
                   id="ConfirmPassword"
                   maxlength="16"
                   name="ConfirmPassword"
                   required
                   onchange="VerifyInput('ConfirmPassword', 'confirmPassword-text'); this.setCustomValidity('');"
                   oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor, preencha este campo.')"
                   title=" " />
            <span id="confirmPassword-text" class="label">Confirmar senha</span>
            <span class="underline"></span>
        </label>

        <div class="submit-container clearfix">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" role="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-irenic float-right" tabindex="0" value="SALVAR" onclick="ClickWait('form');" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Como posso fazer para que essa lista de senhas salvas não seja exibida?

Por que o browser interpreta essa como sendo uma tela de login?

Comment: Isso certamente não resolveria, pois ai eu estaria jogando essa responsabilidade para o usuário. A raiz do problema é que o browser está entendendo este form como se fosse um form de Login, mas não é.

Comment: O que ele está fazendo é perguntado se quer utilizar senhas salvas para os CPFs e CNPJs que foram armazenados no navegador, que em algum momento foram utilizados para fazer login.

Comment: Qual navegador aparece isso?

Comment: O navegador é o firefox.

Comment: Se puder, teste isso, e me comente o resultado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10879/70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é um recurso nativo do navegador e não há como desabilitar via código.

Veja o que diz a [documentação do MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion):

> ### O atributo autocomplete e campos de login
>
> Navegadores modernos implementam gerenciamento de senhas integrado:
>   quando o usuário preenche um usuário e senha para um site, o navegador
>   se oferece para lembrar dos dados para o usuário. Quando o usuário
>   visita o site novamente, o navegador preenche os campos de login
>   automaticamente conforme os valores salvos por ele..
>
> Os navegadores também permitem ao usuário selecionar uma senha mestra
>   para que os dados salvos sejam criptografados.
>
> Mesmo sem uma senha mestra, o gerenciamento de senhas dentro do
>   navegador é geralmente vista como um ganho de segurança. Como os
>   usuários não precisam se lembrar das senhas que o navegador salva para
>   eles, eles podem escolher senhas mais fortes do que geralmente
>   escolheriam.
>
> Por esta razão, muitos navegadores modernos não suportam
>   `autocomplete="off"` para campos de login.
>
> - se um site utiliza `autocomplete="off"` para um `form`, e o formulário inclui campos de usuário e senha, então o navegador ainda
>     assim se oferece para salvar os dados de login, e se o usuário
>     aceitar, o navegador vai preencher estes dados automaticamente na
>     próxima vez que o usuário visita a página.
> - se um site utiliza `autocomplete="off"` para campos `input de usuário e senha`, então o navegador ainda assim se oferece para salvar
>     os dados de login, e se o usuário aceitar, o navegador vai preencher
>     estes dados automaticamente na próxima vez que o usuário visitar a
>     página.
>
> Este comportamento existe no Firefox (desde a versão 38), Google
>   Chrome (desde a versão 34), e Internet Explorer (desde a versão 11).

Concluindo, uma das formas é apagar as senhas memorizadas no Firefox (por exemplo) é clicando com o botão direito do mouse sobre a página e escolher no menu "Ver informações da página":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na aba "Segurança", clicar em "Ver senhas salvas":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em seguida clica em "Remover tudo":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No Chrome digite `chrome://settings/` no navegador, clique em avançado, e veja quadro `Senhas e formulários` https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgMN4.png

Comment: Muito bom, levando em consideração essa informação vou verificar se existe algum meio de contornar essa situação via código. Caso eu consiga volto aqui.